# Bisect and mirror along normal of edge loop created

Tags: modifiers, mirror, bisect

Good morning,

I have 2 spheres and I want to merge them, creating a filled face at the bisector of their intersection.

The fast way is using boolean but I would lose the regularity and I would generate high aspect ratio faces.

[image: 2 spheres]

What I did was bisecting the top sphere (more or less at the bisector line, I don't know how to do it exactly at the middle point), and then clear inner to keep the part that I want. So far so good.

[image]

Then, I select the edge loop and switch to normal axis view. I create a custom axis with alt+space which is called FACE. I then bring in an empty axis and align it to the custom axis (FACE).

[image]

Problem begins now, when I mirror the sphere along the empty Z custom axis, I can't merge the spheres because the spheres are not aligned between them!!
See how the plain axis is not parallel to the sphere bisect line:
[image]

Any tips? I really do not know how to solve this :(